# How to convert a vector into a list in R?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a vector with length of an even number.

```
vec = c(1,3,2,4,5,6)
```

I want to convert it into a list like this, where every 2 consecutive numbers are put into a sub-component.

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 4

[[3]]
[1] 5 6
```

There must be a easy way to do that. It's also OK to convert from a matrix to a list of like this, if it's easier to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `split()`

```
split(vec, (seq_along(vec)-1) %/% 2)
```

Or if you wanted to go to a matrix first, then

```
library(magrittr)   # for %>%
matrix(vec, nrow=2) %>% split(., col(.))
```

Answer (score 2):

split will do:

```
> vec = c(1,3,2,4,5,6)
> split.size <- 2
> split(vec, rep(seq(len=length(vec) / split.size), each=split.size))
$`1`
[1] 1 3

$`2`
[1] 2 4

$`3`
[1] 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lapply :

```
lapply(1:(length(vec)/2),FUN=function(x)c(vec[(x*2)-1],vec[x*2]))
```

Or passing through an intermediate matrix (and data.frame...) :

```
unname(as.list(as.data.frame(matrix(vec,nrow=2))))
```